# Three-column layout, outside elements fill remaining space middle element has size by its content

Tags: html, css, layout

I have problem to make layout as figured at image below:

[image: Page layout]

I need decorate H2 by horizontal lines. Size and position of lines depends on content of H2. The backround of H2 has to be transparent because background behind hasn't solid color.

Do you have any idea how to style this? Any HTML and CSS is allowed, no restrictions.

Comment: There seem to be many, many CSS column layout questions today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to this pure css solution involving both `display: table` and `display: table-cell` (all modern browser and IE > 7, see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

HTML

```
<h2><span>An example of title</span></h2>
```

CSS

```
h2 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


h2 span {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


h2:before, h2:after {
   content : "";
   width   : 50%;
   display : table-cell;
}

h2:before { background: ... /*a line background in position center right; */ }
h2:after  { background: ... /*a line background in position center left; */  }
```

Since your lines end with a very small vertical line you should create two different backgrounds (or a sprite) each one wide at least 50% of your maximum layout width and insert them as background of `before` and `after` pseudoelements of `<h2>`

jsFiddle example (tested on FX9 and CH16): http://jsfiddle.net/PsCrk/2/

Comment: Thank you! I tried this solution before asking, but I ommited width: 50%; and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using HTML and CSS only, but you may want to think about browser compatibility. [This website](http://www.impressivewebs.com/centered-heading-horizontal-line/) shows some great HTML/CSS only solutions and their compatibility with multiple browsers. There is also a method that uses jQuery (on the website).

Comment: This solution breaks one requirement: heading background has to be transparent. All solutions on page uses background: white; to hide line behind heading.

Comment: All you need to do is change the background attribute to `background-color: transparent;` and remove whatever was there before.

Comment: Did you try it? I did and it deosn't work. There was a line throught Heading when I set backgroung: white. As I wrote in the first comment the only trick on that page is hiding line behind white background. That beaks the requirement.